# Point density based on distance to multiple empties

Tags: geometry-nodes

I put together a geometry node set up, that decreases the probabilty of creating a point on the input mesh's vertex if this vertex is closer to the input empties' position:

[image]

[image]

This was fairly simple, but I am now struggling to have multiple empties control the point density.
How do I input a collection of empties?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have almost reached your goal with your construction so far...

In order to be able to get the distance between the individual points and several objects, you need the node `Geometry Proximity`.

Your *Empty* has no geometry, so you have to convert the instances provided by the node `Collection Info` into points using the node `Instances to Points`.

[image]

PS: In your current setup there is still a small problem concerning the scaling:

Since you scaled *Suzanne*, the coordinates don't match the *Empties* anymore.
Either you apply the current scaling to *Suzanne* (*Object > Apply > Scale*), or you switch the transformation in the node `Collection Info` or `Object Info` from *Original* to *Relative*.

[image]